# Attachment Data Type in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I've read that the attachment data type in MS Access should only be used if the database will be use within SharePoint.

Could someone recommend an alternative to this data type? I'm developing a database for users to submit entries and they would like the option to attach notes/pictures with some of the entries.

Comment: I use the attachment data type without SharePoint. I don't see what is has to do with SharePoint. The only downside of it is that it physically stores the attachments in the database. That can make the database get quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I find that storing a path to the file you want to attach is the best option, if it is viable.

If they are images, the image control now has a `ControlSource` property, so you can bind it to a field in the table that contains the path.